# DiscordJS reactionCollector does not work for other users when they react

Tags: javascript, discord.js

My goal is to create a verification system and I want other users (ie. admins) to react to a message from the bot.
The bot sends a message embed to a certain channel and reacts to it with ✅ and ❌. Now all users in this channel should be able to react to this message.

But only the user who requested the verification can react to it (but they shouldn't be able to do this later on) and other users cannot react to it. Nothing happens and no errors. The reaction count just goes up for other users in the channel till the user who requested the verification can react, and then it works and the code continues.

```
        adminChannel.messages.fetch({ limit: 1 }).then(async messages => {
            const lastMessage = messages.first();
            await lastMessage.react('✅');
            await lastMessage.react('❌');

            const filter = (reaction, user) => {
              return ['✅', '❌'].includes(reaction.emoji.name) && !user.bot
            }

            const collector = lastMessage.createReactionCollector(filter, { max: 1 });

            collector.on('collect', async (reaction, user) => {
                if (reaction.emoji.name === '✅') {
                    //do something
                } else {
                    //do something
                }
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the `ReactionCollectorOptions` parameter in `lastMessage.createReactionCollector(filter, { max: 1 })` because `max: 1` will make the bot stop awaiting reactions after the first reaction was added. You can just use `lastMessage.createReactionCollector(filter)` if you don't need this option.
If you still have doubts you can check [here](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/typedef/ReactionCollectorOptions) the documentation for `ReactionCollectorOptions` and [here](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Message?scrollTo=createReactionCollector) the documentation for `createReactionCollector` method.

Comment: This does not fix the problem. I removed the `max:1` but the issue still persists. Anyway in my filter I have defined `!user.bot` and that will filter out the reactions the bot gives to his own message.

Comment: Yeah the filter is ok. I think you can try to enable intents and partials if it still doesn't work. You can enable intents on Discord Dev Portal => _Your Bot Application_ => Bot => Intents. And you can add partials in client options, when you instantiate the new Client so like this: `const client = new Discord.Client({ partials: ['REACTION']})` You can add other partials in the array. All the partials are listed [here](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/typedef/PartialType).